# @ipld/car - carReader for large files (Content Addressed Archive)

Tags: storage, ipfs, nft, js-ipfs

I'm trying to create a reader from a .car file (Content Addressed Archive) using `@ipld/car`. The documentation shows how to create a `carReader` when files are small as per below:

```js
import { CarReader } from '@ipld/car'

const inStream = fs.createReadStream('example.car');
// read and parse the entire stream in one go, this will cache the contents of
// the car in memory so is not suitable for large files.
const reader = await CarReader.fromIterable(inStream);
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ipld/car)

**Question:** If I have a file at `C:\output.car`, and it's say 10GB and larger than my available RAM, how can I create a reader for this large `.car` file?

I think it should be one of these methods, but there's no sample code on how to use it...

```js
import { CarBlockIterator } from '@ipld/car/iterator';
// or
import { CarCIDIterator } from '@ipld/car/iterator';
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ipld/car#CarBlockIterator)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. This works:

```js
import { CarIndexedReader } from '@ipld/car';

const filename = "C:\output.car"
const carReader = await CarIndexedReader.fromFile(filename);
```